# Describe the flow of events and sequence diagram of a shared use case

Tags: uml, use-case, sequence-diagram, visual-paradigm, use-case-diagram

I have this kind of situation where I have multiple actors which share the same use case.

I cannot figure out from which point of view I should write the flow of events and describe the sequence diagram of this specific use case, having more than one single actor.

Comment: You should write scenario from the point of view of the use case

Comment: How can I properly do it? I've always wrote from the actor's point of view.

Comment: Traditionally you write scenario's as conversation between the actor and the system: 1) The Actor does xxx 2) The system does yyy 3 ) The actor does zzz etc... without specifying which of the (primary) actors exactly. Adding or removing a (primary) actor should not change the use case.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

> **You:** *I have multiple actors which share the same use case.
>
>   ... from which point of view I should write the flow of events*

Use-cases are goal-oriented. They are not supposed to be a functional decomposition nor a sequence of actions.  It's not me, but Ivar Jacobson, the inventor of use-cases, in *[Use-Case 2.0](https://www.ivarjacobson.com/sites/default/files/field_iji_file/article/use-case_2_0_jan11.pdf)*:

> A use case is all the ways of using a system to achieve a particular goal for a particular user.
>  (Page 4)

So use-cases are meant to provide the big picture.  Your use-case diagram should identify these independent goals.  Of course, behind each use case, you have some narrative that describe the interaction between the actors and the use-case:

> The purpose of a use-case narrative is to tell the story of how the system and its actors work together to achieve a particular goal. (...)
>   Use-case narratives can be developed at different levels of detail ranging from a simple outline, identifying the basic flow and the most important variants, through to a comprehensive, highly detailed specification
> (Page 47)

One way of describing this flow, is how [Geert Bellekens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2018133/geert-bellekens) explained in the comments:  describing the scenario telling who does what in which order.  A variant of this presentation is a tabular form: a column for the actor actions and a column for the actor actions.

Now, if you're at the beginning of the design,  and especially if you have several actors, this kind of UC description forces you to make a decision about the way you design the interactions.  A more creative variant is to describe [**essential** use-cases](http://agilemodeling.com/artifacts/essentialUseCase.htm):  instead of describing the flow of event, you make a table describing mapping more in detail the intents (i.e. intentions) of the actors (in one or n columns) to the corresponding responsibilities of the system  (in a separate column).

You can then start to think about possible sequences, but also about alternative sequences that could provide a better user experience or a more optimal flow of information. The flexibility is so high that you could even design voice-driven or NLP driven interfaces in which the sequence is not predetermined but could be different for each use-case execution.